# How to use P1787 to interpret why the static local variable in inline function refers to the same object

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++23

[P1787](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r5.html) has an excellent description for what are the same entity.

> Two declarations of entities declare the same entity if, considering declarations of unnamed types to introduce their names for linkage purposes, if any ([dcl.typedef], [dcl.enum]), they correspond ([basic.scope.scope]), have the same target scope that is not a function or template parameter scope, and either
>
> > 1. they appear in the same translation unit, or
> > 2. they both declare names with module linkage and are attached to the same module, or
> > 3. they both declare names with external linkage.

So, consider this example:

```cpp
// a.hpp
inline int& function(){
   static int value = 0; // #1
   return value;
}
----------------------
//b.cpp
#include "a.hpp"
void g(){
  auto&& rf = function();
}
----------------------
//c.cpp
#include "a.hpp"
int main(){
 auto&& rf0 = function();
}
```

Except for the note says that:

> [ Note: An inline function or variable with external or module linkage can be defined in multiple translation units([basic.def.odr]), but is one entity with one address. A type or variable defined in the body of such a function is therefore **a single entity**.--end note]

However, let's consider the `value` declared at `#1`. In `b`'s TU and `c`'s TU, these two declarations for `value` are corresponding, and they have the same target scope which is introduced by the compound-statement of `function`. However, a local variable does not have any linkage, so neither bullet in that list will be satisfied. So, why two declarations for `value`(in the body of the function) in different two translate units declared the same entity? How to interpret that through the rule in P1787?

Comment: `why two declarations for value` Mostly because [a static local variable in an inline function with external or module linkage always refers to the same object](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.inline-6).

Comment: @KamilCuk I know that **Note** (as I mentioned in my question), my subject for this question is how to use the **formal rule** about the same entity written in P1787 to interpret this question.

Comment: _variable in inline function refers to the same entity_ Variable doesn't refer to an entity, variable **is** an entity. But P1787 doesn't seem to explicitly specify that such variables refer to the same object.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  yup,  variable is an entity. Maybe  use the word "denote" is more precise.  In other word, why two declarations  for `value` in two TUs declare the same entity.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the program (assuming that the usual ODR constraints are satisfied) is as if there were **one** definition of `function`.  Whichever definition that is contains the **only** (operative) declaration of `value`, which of course declares only one entity.

Note that this singularity of definition is so strong that it is able to make “two different” **lambda** expressions produce the same closure type without any notion of linkage; it is certainly capable of suppressing a declaration for the purposes of object identity without the assistance of [basic.link].

Comment: However, that's the result of all conditions of [basic.def.odr#13](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#13) that are satisfied.  One of these conditions is: In each such definition, corresponding names, looked up according to [basic.lookup], shall refer to **the same entity**. Assume we are in determine whether these `function`s satisfy these conditions, we should first determine whether `value` refer to the same entity. How should I do that?

Comment: @jackX: This very subtle point has been recently addressed in [basic.def.odr]/14, which says that you presume that the rules are satisfied for each entity, and that contained entities exist only once, when evaluating the requirements for another entity.  The lookup for `value` in each definition is therefore allowed to find its corresponding static variable for the purposes of establishing ODR compliance, which then satisfies the presumption by making them the same variable.

Comment: Could you cite a link about that addressing? appreciate that. I don't see the corresponding wording in [basic.def.odr#14](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14)

Comment: Shouldn't [basic.def.odr]/13 just exclude names which resolve to entities declared in the function/class itself?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: C++17 did that, but CWG2300 replaced it with the trick in /14 so as to properly handle lambdas.

Comment: @jackX: It’s the “including in the application of these requirements to other entities” sentence and the preceding one about contained entities.

Comment: @DavisHerring   C++17 gives a clear wording, that is: in each definition of D, corresponding names, looked up according to [basic.lookup], **shall refer to an entity defined within the definition of D** or shall refer to the same entity, after overload resolution and after matching of partial template specialization. However, such wording has been changed in c++20, which make the definition circular.

Comment: @DavisHerring Honestly, I don't read that meaning from "These requirements also apply to corresponding entities defined within each definition of D". Instead, My understanding of this sentence is the above requirement shall be satisfied by the entity defined within `D`

Comment: @jackX: It’s the “For each such entity […] other entities.”; that lets *D* make the assumption concerning its own contents.

Comment: @DavisHerring I read the rule again and again.  My understanding is still:  Only all requirements  listed in [basic.def.odr/13] are satisfied will the assumption be applied to these `D` and other entity that is required to satisfy /13. (as if there is a single entity with a single definition, including in the application of these requirements to other entities.).  You seems to mean, we should first assume they're the same entity, and based on this assumption then determine whether /13 all be satisfied.